# Listing Form Templates within another Controller view

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a form_templates table and a forms table.  They're connected by form_template_id.  I want to be able to list the form_templates that have been created by title within a select.ctp file I have created within the Forms controller.  Just wanting some direction on how to do this with cakephp?

At the moment I have the following code within my FormsController:

```
    public function select()
{
    $this->set('page_heading', 'Current Forms');

    $contain = [];

    $formTemplate = $this->FormTemplates->Forms->find('list', ['order' => 'title'])->where(['active'=>true]);

    $forms = $this->paginate($this->Forms->FormTemplates);
    $this->set(compact('forms', 'formTemplate'));
}
```

But I am getting a Call to a member function find() on null error.

Any help on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.  I know it would be simple but I am new to cakephp.

Comment: Load model(`$this->loadModel('FormTemplates')`) before calling `$formTemplate = $this->FormTemplates->Forms->find('list', ['order' => 'title'])->where(['active'=>true]);`.

Comment: Thanks @Ishanvyas22 but I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FormsController` only `FormsTable` is loaded automatically, and you are trying to access model that is not currently loaded:

```
$formTemplate = $this->FormTemplates->Forms->find(...
```

To get what you want, you should access associated `FormTemplatesTable` like this:

```
$formTemplate = $this->Forms->FormTemplates->find(...
```

Comment: Thanks Szymon.  I have added this but still have the same error.  Both tables are linked with an inner join.  I have setup the select.ctp table consisting of the below:

    <?php if (!empty($form->form_templates)): ?>
        <div class="">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="toggletable">
            <thead>

and tbody starts with:

    <?php foreach ($form->form_template as $formTemplates): ?>

Comment: If you still have this error, please share full error text with full stacktrace.